# Query to find the mismatched records in two tables without a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select the mismatched records from two tables (shown below) using a full outer join and a where clause (query written below). Both the tables don't have a primary key. I think because of the outer join, I am getting all the 3 records in the result. Is there a way to return only the records that have been mismatched by modifying the query? (i.e 3rd record).

table1:

[image]

table2:

[image]

Query Used:

```
    DECLARE @table1 TABLE  (element_type varchar(100),element_code  varchar(100), value varchar(100))
    DECLARE @table2 TABLE  (element_type varchar(100),element_code  varchar(100), value varchar(100))
    
    Insert into @table1
    values
    ('ABC', 'CODE1', 'Interest Due'),
    ('ABC', 'CODE1', NULL),
    ('BCD', 'CODE2', 'value1')
    
    Insert into @table2
    values
    ('ABC', 'CODE1', 'Interest Due'),
    ('ABC', 'CODE1', NULL),
    ('BCD', 'CODE2', 'value2')
    
    SELECT  
            [Element Type] = ISNULL(m1.element_type, m2.element_type),
            [Differences]  = 'value missmatch'
        FROM    
            @table1 m1 
            FULL OUTER JOIN @table2 m2 
                ON m1.element_type = m2.element_type AND m1.element_code = m2.element_code
        WHERE
        ISNULL(m1.value, '') <> ISNULL(m2.value, '')
```

Output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: I would expect this to return five records. This question would work better if you included your sample data as insert statements

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I have updated the query with the insert statements.

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this is to find all of the records that match exactly, then exclude them from the mismatch process.

Comment: This is basically an `EXCEPT ALL` query, but SQL Server does not support that syntax

Answer (score 2):

[Set Operators - EXCEPT and INTERSECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
WITH result AS (
  (SELECT * FROM @table1 UNION SELECT * FROM @table2)
  EXCEPT
  (SELECT * FROM @table1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM @table2)
)
SELECT DISTINCT element_type, element_code, 'value missmatch' AS Differences
FROM result;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=50becff122f4775eb92348082618ba4a)

Answer (score 1):

Include all columns into ON clause respecting nullability

```
SELECT  distinct
        [Element Type] = ISNULL(m1.element_type, m2.element_type),
        [Differences]  = 'value missmatch'
    FROM    
        table1 m1 
        FULL OUTER JOIN table2 m2 
            ON m1.element_type = m2.element_type 
               AND m1.element_code = m2.element_code 
               AND (m1.value = m2.value or m1.value IS NULL and m2.value IS NULL)
    WHERE m1.element_type IS NULL OR m2.element_type IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not clear, but the query below produces the output you want.

```
SELECT  
       [Element Type] = m1.element_type,
           [Differences]  = 'value missmatch'
       FROM    
            @table1 m1 
            Left JOIN @table2 m2 
                ON m1.element_type = m2.element_type AND m1.element_code = m2.element_code AND m1.value != m2.value
WHERE m1.value IS NOT NULL AND m2.value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: `table2 ('BCD', 'CODE2', NULL)` is an example when it doesn't work.